# Can't find text source file in WP theme

Tags: php

The site is http://www.rimongod.ee

I'm having trouble with locating the file that holds the text "REDESIGN YOURSELF" that sits under the header image. There's nothing in index.php, header.php or one of the few dozens of php files that come with this wordpress theme. :/

Could anyone tell me the file that houses this text?

Comment: It would help if you would post the theme name/download link etc

Comment: Hello @user54286 - Welcome to the WordPress Development community! Please note that questions regarding 3rd-party plugins and themes are considered off-topic within our community as it's rare that many if any of our members have experience with such items, and thus questions regarding them tend to go unanswered. The best place to receive support for such items is the 3rd-party's official support channels. Please review the [ask] section of our [help] to learn more about what questions are [on-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and a good fit at WPSE.

Comment: All of that said, while the manner in which your question is phrased implies that the issue pertains to a theme, there is chance that this has to do with WordPress core - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

The "REDESIGN YOURSELF" text on the linked website appears to be the blog's tagline - a short sentence or catch phrase describing the blog. You can change your tagline via the field provided in the administration dashboard on the `Settings > General` page.

See [this entry from WordPress.com's support section](http://en.support.wordpress.com/settings/general-settings/#changing-your-site-title-and-tagline) for more information.

<sub>(note that while the WordPress Development community does not for the most part provide support for WordPress.com or it's services, in this instance the linked article is relevant to the WordPress platform as a whole - both WordPress.com sites as well as custom installations of the WordPress.org open-source project).</sub>

Comment: right you are! It is the tagline. But where could it be located on the ftp server?

Comment: It's stored in the database within the `wp_options` table. You should alter/remove it by editing the field on the settings page that I mentioned. You can also remove it by adding custom code to your installation, but such a solution is unnecessary given that you can do so through the dashboard, and without making the tagline hard-coded, to boot.